# Tensorflow unnormalized log probabilities

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-probability, probability-distribution

I am using Tensorflow to create some probabilities. I am trying to estimate the unnormalized log probabilities, following the documentation in tensorflow:

```
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
tfd = tfp.distributions

dist                  = tfd.Normal(loc=0., scale=3.)
sample                = dist.sample([3])
normalized_log_prob   = dist.log_prob(sample)
unnormalized_log_prob = dist.unnormalized_log_prob(sample)
```

Despite there exist `unnormalized_log_prob` in the Tensorflow documentation, I have this error:

```
AttributeError: 'Normal' object has no attribute 'unnormalized_log_prob'
```

I need a general approach to obtain the unnormalized log probabilites, not just for `Normal` as I am using `Normal` just an example.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What does `tfp.__version__` tell you? `unnormalized_log_prob` is only in the latest `tensorflow-probability==0.13.0` and `tfp-nightly`. Also, note that `unnormalized_log_prob` is currently almost always the same thing as `log_prob`, except in, say, `JointDistributionPinned`.

Comment: Thank you. What is the compatible version of tensorflow for this. I have tf.__version__==2.4.1 and it is compatible with tfp.__version__==0.12.2

Comment: TFP 0.13 is the version you would need.